# Как корректнее сделать из массива чисел строку с номером телефона?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Пытаюсь решить задачу на code wars. Дается массив из 10-ти чисел, задача - написать функцию которая вернет строку представляющую собой номер телефона. То есть дан например, массив:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Функция должна вернуть `"(123) 456-7890"`

Я написал, что называется "в лоб". Вот код:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  if(numbers.length === 10){
    let result = "(";
    for (let i =0; i<= 2; ++i)
    result += numbers[i].toString();
    result += ") ";
    for (let i = 3; i <= 5; ++i){
      result += numbers[i].toString();
    }
    result += "-";
    for (let i = 6; i< numbers.length; ++i) result += numbers[i].toString();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Он прошел все тесты, но мне любопытно можно ли встроить скобочки и тире как-то... красивее что ли?  В общем, не через три цикла. Может методы массива какие использовать или еще каким-то способом. Буду благодарен за наводки и помощь.

Comment: В Codewars есть раздел со всеми решениями этой задачи. Просто посмотри варианты решений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот кто-то решил так:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  let format = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";
  
  for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
    format = format.replace('x', numbers[i]);
  }
  
  return format;
}
```

Просто же... А есть вообще в одну строку через регулярки:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  return numbers.join('').replace(/(...)(...)(.*)/, '($1) $2-$3');
}
```